# JavaScript date format convert.

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Date from datetimepicker have format:

```
var currentDate = new Date(); currentDate = Thu Jul 14 2016 09:10:04 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni) {}
```

And this date have methods like `.getFullYear()` etc.

But when I send it to my API where this date is `DateTime` and send back it to frontend it look that `2016-07-22T22:00:00Z` and it doesn't have methods like `.getFullYear()` etc.

That is problem for me. I need detect if the date is formatted  `yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ssZ` and convert it to the first format.

How I can do it? I can't use momentjs.

Comment: "I can't use momentjs." What an odd thing to say... it means you already know momentjs is a good solution. :-) Why can't you use it?

Comment: It's also note at all clear to me you how you're parsing the value returned by your frontend.

Comment: Isn't enough parse the string to the Date constructor? like `var d = new Date('2016-07-22T22:00:00Z');d.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 1):

format your date string in javascript

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();        
var month = date.getMonth();   
var year = date.getFullYear();  
var hour = date.getHours();     
var minute = date.getMinutes(); 
var second = date.getSeconds(); 

var datetime= day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
```

Then in c#

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DatetimeString , "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use this:
http://momentjs.com/

this allows all sorts if formatting and its safer to use due to incorrect dates possible

```
var a = moment('2016-01-01'); 
var b = a.add(1, 'week'); 
a.format();
"2016-01-08T00:00:00-06:00"

moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jul 14th 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard format `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`

You're possibly receiving a string from your API. So you have to parse it back to Date object

```
var newDateObject = new Date(dateStringFromAPI);
```

Then you can access `newDateObject.getDay()` `newDateObject.getFullYear()`  etc

Answer (score 0):

as you are using AngularJS you can simply format date with Angular's date filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you!

Looks like the front-end doesn't parse the API-dataset to create a date-object (no date-object—no date-methods)—here is a solution:

1. Enable date-parsing on the front-end;
2. If needed, apply a date-time format on API output (MSDN-articles: Date and Time Format Strings—[Standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx));
3. Send the API-processed data to the front-end.